# Is there a way we can insert a Map<String,Object> onto the Cassandra Table using QueryBuilder for a dynamic table(Table with no model class)

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, query-builder, dynamic-tables

```
public int save(String tableName, Map<String, Object> dataMap) throws IllegalAccessException {
    SimpleStatement saveStatement = QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).values()
            



    return 1;

}
```

I have tried other inbuilt methods of QueryBuilder to save map values as a whole but only a map of type map<String,Term> can be used to save data if "values()" method is used and I already have a map<String,Object>.This needs to be done for a dynamic table p.s. I am not that much familiar with Dynamic Tables. The other method I tried using with a return type integer was

```
public int save(String tableName, Map<String, Object> dataMap) throws IllegalAccessException {



    SimpleStatement updateStatement = QueryBuilder.update(tableName)
            .set(appendSet(dataMap))
            .where(appendWhere(domainId))
            .build();
    log.info(updateStatement.getQuery());

    return 1;
}
private Iterable<Assignment> appendSet(Map<String, Object> dataMap) throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : dataMap.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.getName().equals("key")) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.get(dataMap) != null) {
                    if (field.getType().equals(Long.class)) {
                        assignments.add(Assignment.setColumn(field.getName(), literal(Long.valueOf(field.get(dataMap).toString()))));
                    } else {
                        assignments.add(Assignment.setColumn(field.getName(), literal(field.get(dataMap))));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                log.catching(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return assignments;
}

private Iterable<Relation> appendWhere(Object key) {
    List<Relation> relations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Field field : key.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(key) != null) {
                if (field.getType().equals(Long.class)) {
                    relations.add(Relation.column(field.getName()).isEqualTo(literal(Long.valueOf(field.get(key).toString()))));
                } else {
                    relations.add(Relation.column(field.getName()).isEqualTo(literal(field.get(key))));
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            log.catching(e);
        }
    }
    return relations;
}
```

This probably didn't work out too. I need to return an integer with the save method but I just cannot figure out how to insert map values into the cassandra table itself using QueryBuilders or CassandraTemplate. I am working with Cassandra Database and my table is dynamic. Can anyone suggest me a good article or anything? I found articles but those did not help me insert map key value pairs into the table so I am quite struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cassandra Data Modelling reminders**

With Cassandra there is no such things as dynamic tables, it works with a strict schema. I would argue that if you did not find any samples it is because it is an anti-pattern.

With a Cassandra databases you start by designing your queries and ONLY THEN define the tables because **you can only filter on fields (part of where clause) within the primary key. I mentionned this as `Iterable<Relation> appendWhere(Object key)` is suspicious, there is no joins nor relations in Cassandra.

If a new query arise on the same data, you duplicate the data in another table (yes, it is different for relational or document oriented)

At initialization of your application you `prepare` your (static) statements to validate syntax and share a `PrepareStatementID` with the server.

```java
@PostConstruct
public void prepareStatements() {
   PreparedStatement  stmtCreateUser = 
   session.prepare(QueryBuilder.insertInto(USER_TABLENAME)
                .value(USER_EMAIL, QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                .value(USER_FIRSTNAME, QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                .value(USER_LASTNAME, QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                .ifNotExists().build());
}
```

^ Noticed the constants used in the definition. Later when you reuse the column names for extra tables or rename the columns it is way easier to debug.

Given a table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_by_city (
    city name,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    email text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((city), lastname, firstname, email)
);
```

*Legal but not recommended:*

```sql
// This query is legal but never forget the where clause or you do full scan cluster
SELECT [fields] FROM users_by_city;

// This query is legal as you provide the partition in the where clause but having * in the select is hazardous if columns are added later.
SELECT * FROM users_by_city WHERE city=?
```

*Legal Queries*

```sql
SELECT firstname,lastname,email FROM users_by_city WHERE city=?

SELECT firstname,email FROM users_by_city WHERE city=? and lastname=?

// order is important
SELECT firstname,email FROM users_by_city WHERE city=? and lastname=? and firstname=?
```

*Illegal Queries*

```sql
// city is required in PK
SELECT firstname,email FROM users_by_city WHERE lastname=? and firstname=?

// order of cluster columns are important
SELECT firstname,email FROM users_by_city WHERE a city=?  and firstname=?
```

**Implementation Details**

With all those reminders *(sorry if you knew already all this thinking of those who might come to the question later...)* here is some ideas.

`QueryBuilder` is already a builder to build your queries dynamically but looking at your code you can think of

*INSERT*

```java
public SimpleStatement insertInto(String keyspace, 
  String tableName, Map<String, Object> fields) {
  return QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace, tableName)
                     .values(fields.entrySet()
                         .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                             entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                             entry -> QueryBuilder.literal(entry.getValue()))))
                     .build();
}
```

*SELECT*

```java
public SimpleStatement selectFrom(String keyspace, String tableName, Map<String, Relation> fields) {
        return QueryBuilder.selectFrom(keyspace, tableName)
                           .columns(fields.keySet())
                           .where(fields.values())
                           .build();
        
    }
```

**Extra resources**

- [More informations could be found in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/query_builder/)
- [Hope this code could help you](https://github.com/KillrVideo/killrvideo-java/blob/master/killrvideo-service-videocatalog/src/main/java/com/killrvideo/service/video/dao/VideoCatalogDseDao.java)

Comment: Much appreciated. Although i found a little different approach.. this was what i was looking for.